# SQL join statement with multiple columns

Tags: join, left-join

I have two tables like the following:

players:

```
id | name | location 
1  | john | australia
2  | anne | u.s. 
3  | jen  | germany
```

games:

```
player | points | player2 | points2
john   | 2      | anne    | 1 
anne   | 1      | jen     | 3 
jen    | 3      | john    | 4 
jen    | 4      | anne    | 1
```

I want the SQL statement to return each player's name, his or her location, and the total points each has accumulated through all games he or she participated in.
I tried to do a left join but I couldn't get this to work.

Comment: You should use player IDs in the `games` table, not names.

Comment: @user: You should consider accepting answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, location, SUM(total_points) AS total_points
FROM (
    SELECT name, location, COALESCE(SUM(points), 0) AS total_points
    FROM players p
    LEFT JOIN games g ON p.name = g.player
    GROUP BY name, location
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, location, COALESCE(SUM(points2), 0)
    FROM players p
    LEFT JOIN games g ON p.name = g.player2
    GROUP BY name, location
) x
GROUP BY name, location
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0eb5/5)

Comment: For the above table, this produces Anne-2, Jen-3, and John-14, which isn't right.  Hmm… @Barmar

Comment: Fixed, I left out one of the `GROUP BY` clauses in the `UNION`.